# Xamarin Profiler instrumenting Startup Time? How to Read?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

my apps startup time became extremely slow. I end up 15 secs here and I profiled using Xamarin Profiler on VS 2017 enterprise. Here is how it looks like

This is the slowest line shown in the profiler but I dont really understand what it tells me?  there is not method or class name.

[image]

Most interesting thing is entire MainActivity with App initialization takes around 800ms as shown below with red lines highlighted.

[image]

So my questions are what consumes in the screenshot1? how/what am I supposed to optimize if my mainactivity completes in 800ms?

Comment: Are you using System.Threading? I created an empty project and searched the profiler,  didn't found any System.Threading usage. Could you please post the related codes?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT no I wasnt I found out that it is cause by xamarin insights
when I call the line   Xamarin.Insights.Initialize(InsightsID, this.ApplicationContext);

Answer (score 1):

I went deeper down and analyzed almost each line how fast they are executed. below are the nuget packages I am using. You need to initiliaze all these within mainactivity on create method. some are slow. Like I was using xamarin insights although it is deprecated for hockeyapp(Hockeyapp and mobile center still dont have custom exception tracking. thats why I was keen to keep xamarin insights until they get this feature). So I removed it and I removed xamarin Light theme. I am now down to 5-6 secs. It would be great to have 2-3secs of course but this is still something :) I hope this helps to others who has problem with startup time.

Xamarin.forms Light theme takes 1.1 secs to initialize as shown below

[image]

Acr.userdialogs is fine.

[image]

MobileAds.Initialize

[image]

HockeyApp

[image]

FFImageLoading

[image]

Xamarin Inisghts

[image]

Xamarin.Forms.Applink

[image]